# Riddle in two parts

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

This riddle is in two parts, giving two different solutions which complement each other.

1. > I have two that are different,
   >   I often grow to be stronger,
   >   And when you come into me,
   >   I might be found in the sea.
2. > I have two both the same,
   >   One day I might bifurcate,
   >   And the biggest part of me
   >   Can be found in in real life.

Can you solve the riddles to find both solutions?

Comment: I would like to request a few clarifications -- with, of course, the understanding that the author may not wish to give them.

Comment: First: is the last line of #2 really meant to say "in in real life" rather than just "in real life"?

Comment: Second: Rand, do your puzzling principles permit unmarked homophones? That is, could "when you come into me" mean something about inserting a letter U, or not? (I am not asking whether it *does*.)

Comment: Third: does "two different solutions" mean (a) one solution to each of the two parts, or (b) two solutions to the whole thing?

Comment: @Gareth **1)** I could tell you, but then I'd have to kill you :-) **2)** I'm not very strict about marking types of clue in riddles. If I was writing a crossword, I might try to learn the Ximenean rules first, but for a riddle, things like unmarked homophones are par for the course. (No comment on whether or not there are any in this particular riddle.) **3)** Definitely a): one solution to each part, giving two solutions which complement each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answers are:

> Boy and Girl

Riddle 1:
I have two that are different,

> Boys have an X and Y Chromosome

I often grow to be stronger

> Boys become Men

And when you come into me, I might be found in the sea.

> Add a 'U' to 'Boy' to get 'Buoy,' found in the sea.

Riddle 2:
I have two both the same,

> Girls have two X Chromosomes

One day I might bifurcate,

> Girls become women who may give birth

And the biggest part of me can be found in in real life.

> Most of the word 'Girl' can be found in the abbreviation for 'in real life,' which is 'IRL'

Comment: Yessss! Well done!

Comment: Man that was some very impressive puzzling for a very well-written riddle. I wish I'd thought of that!!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think my answer is 100% right, but maybe it will work toward the right answer :)

1=

> H2O (or maybe OH)

I have two that are different,

> Oxygen and hydrogen

I often grow to be stronger,

> Not sure about this one, but I think it has to do with hydrogen bonds.

And when you come into me,
I might be found in the sea.

> The sea consist out of water

2=

> 02 (oxygen)

I have two both the same,

> 2 times oxygen

One day I might bifurcate,

> O2 can bifurcate when it gets extremely heat (I think), and when it attach itself to another molecule. Correct me if i'm wrong!

And the biggest part of me
Can be found in in real life.

> We breath oxygen and a big part of the air consist of oxygen

The connection between 1 and 2:

> Water and oxygen complement each other

Comment: I was thinking something like this, but I wasn't completely sure. +1

Comment: I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree here. The third line has more significance than you've given it, and the two solutions 'complementing' each other means more than just two different kinds of molecule.